# Delay in playing sound

Tags: android

In android I have a listener set up on a view so that when it it is pressed it will play a sound.  I am playing the sound using soundpool.

The problem I have is there is a small delay between the press and the sound playing.  Any idea how that could be happening?

Comment: It's happening because the system has to load the sound.  Is it a second or more?  Then it might be a different issue.  But if you want the sound to play instantly, you need to cache it before hand.

Comment: How can you cache it using soundpool? Nah, its only like a few hundred milliseconds but that's still to slow